# Implementing long press by usng timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

The program is basically to drag and drop JPanel. I wanted to implement long press to select a JPanel and usage of timer is suggested in few tutorials. Therefore, I tried using timer for 1000ms to select a JPanel, but it works in the preferred way only once but with some flickering of a JPanel which I don't understand why. It fails to recognize mousepressed function later. Another problem is, when clicked on a JPanel, panels start to get removed unintentionally. Actually nothing should happen when a JPanel is clicked as I haven't written anything for Clicked function. 
Please provide some suggestions to remove the above mentioned problems
Thanks in advance.

```
package swappaneleg;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SwapPanelEg extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1594039652438249918L;
private static final int PREF_W = 400;
private static final int PREF_H = 400;
private static final int MAX_COLUMN_PANELS = 8;
private JPanel columnPanelsHolder = new JPanel();

public SwapPanelEg(){
  columnPanelsHolder.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLUMN_PANELS; i++) {
     int number = i + 1;
     int width = 20 + i * 3;
     int height = PREF_H - 30;
     columnPanelsHolder.add(new ColumnPanel(number, width, height));
  }

  MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
  columnPanelsHolder.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
  columnPanelsHolder.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  add(columnPanelsHolder);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}

private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
private JComponent selectedPanel;
private Point deltaLocation;
private JPanel placeHolder = new JPanel();
private JComponent glassPane;
        java.util.Timer t;

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent evt) {
     if (evt.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        return;
     }

     if(t == null) {
       t = new java.util.Timer();
     }
     t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
         JPanel source = (JPanel) evt.getSource();
         selectedPanel = (JComponent) source.getComponentAt(evt.getPoint());

         if (selectedPanel == null) {
         return;
         }

         if (selectedPanel == source) {
         selectedPanel = null;
         return;
         }

         glassPane = (JComponent) SwingUtilities.getRootPane(source).getGlassPane();
         glassPane.setVisible(true);
         Point glassPaneOnScreen = glassPane.getLocationOnScreen();
         glassPane.setLayout(null);
         Point ptOnScreen = evt.getLocationOnScreen();
         Point panelLocOnScreen = selectedPanel.getLocationOnScreen();

         int deltaX = ptOnScreen.x + glassPaneOnScreen.x - panelLocOnScreen.x;
         int deltaY = ptOnScreen.y + glassPaneOnScreen.y - panelLocOnScreen.y;

         deltaLocation = new Point(deltaX, deltaY);

         Component[] allComps = source.getComponents();
         for (Component component : allComps) {

         if (component == selectedPanel) {
           placeHolder.setPreferredSize(selectedPanel.getPreferredSize());
           source.add(placeHolder);
           selectedPanel.setSize(selectedPanel.getPreferredSize());

           int x = ptOnScreen.x - deltaLocation.x;
           int y = ptOnScreen.y - deltaLocation.y;
           selectedPanel.setLocation(x, y);
           glassPane.add(selectedPanel);
           repaint();

         } 
         else {
           source.add(component);
           repaint();
         }
         }

         }
         },1000,500);

         revalidate();               
         repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {

     if (selectedPanel != null) {
        Point ptOnScreen = evt.getLocationOnScreen();

        int x = ptOnScreen.x - deltaLocation.x;
        int y = ptOnScreen.y - deltaLocation.y;
        selectedPanel.setLocation(x, y);
        selectedPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        selectedPanel.setOpaque(false);
        repaint();
         if(t != null)
                {
                    t.cancel();
                    t = null;
                }

     }


  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
     if (evt.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        return;
     }



     if (selectedPanel == null) {
        return;
     }

     JComponent source = (JComponent) evt.getSource();

     Component[] allComps = source.getComponents();
     JPanel overComponent = (JPanel) source.getComponentAt(evt
           .getPoint());



     if (overComponent != null && overComponent != placeHolder
           && overComponent != source) {
        for (Component component : allComps) {

             if (component == overComponent) {

                 source.add(overComponent);
                 source.add(selectedPanel);
                 source.remove(placeHolder);
              selectedPanel.setOpaque(true);
              selectedPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0,0,0,0)));


            }
             else {
              source.add(component);
              source.remove(placeHolder);
              selectedPanel.setOpaque(true);
              selectedPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0,0,0,0)));

           }
        }
     }

     else {
        for (Component component : allComps) {
            if (component == placeHolder) {
               source.add(selectedPanel);
               source.remove(placeHolder);
              } 
            else {
                source.remove(placeHolder);
              source.add(component);
              selectedPanel.setOpaque(true);
              selectedPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0,0,0,0)));

           }
        }
     }  
     revalidate();
     repaint();
     selectedPanel = null;
     if(t != null)
                {
                    t.cancel();
                    t = null;
                }

  }
}


private static void createAndShowGui() {
  SwapPanelEg mainPanel = new SwapPanelEg();

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwapPanelEg");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
     }
  });
}
}
class ColumnPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5366233209639059032L;
private int number;
private int prefWidth;
private int prefHeight;

public ColumnPanel(int number, int prefWidth, int prefHeight) {
  setName("ColumnPanel " + number);
  this.number = number;
  this.prefWidth = prefWidth;
  this.prefHeight = prefHeight;

  add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(number)));

  setBackground(Color.cyan);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(prefWidth, prefHeight);
}

public int getNumber() {
  return number;
}

}
```

Comment: hmmm without usage of util.Timer can make me sence, use Swing Timer instead, repaint() couldn't be alive EDT from events wrapped into util.Timer, short answer nothing will be repainted or on very volatille period, animations isn't smooth

Comment: Note that, when clicking a mouse-button, you will get calles to mousePressed(), mouseReleased(), and finally mouseClicked(). click = press + release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution would be:

- Create a `SwingTimer` when a mouse is first pressed.
- Have it wait a second and track if the mouse was released or leaves the panel.
- If by the time the `SwingTimer` ends there has been no release and the mouse didn't leave the panel then process with your task.

SwingTimer tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Proposed timer code:

```
private class InnerTimer implements Runnable {
    public boolean expired;
    public boolean cancelled;
    private long end;
    public void run() {
        expired = cancelled = false;
        end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
        while ( ! cancelled && ! expired) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= end) {
               expired = true;
            } else {
               try { Thread.sleep(100); } 
               catch(InterruptedException e) {/* no big deal */}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep an `InnerTimer innerTimer = new InnerTimer();` in each panel that needs to listen for long-presses. When the mouse is pressed on such a panel, start this timer in a separate thread: `(new Thread(innerTimer)).start()`. If the mouse leaves the panel, or is released, cancel the timer: `innerTimer.cancelled = true;`. If the mouse is moved, check if the timer expired naturally: `if (innerTimer.expired)`; if it did, then the user has successfully long-clicked on this panel. If it did not expire, then just cancel the timer.

Note that this code is somewhat quick&dirty. However, it is short and relatively efficient (except in that it creates threads, but these mostly sleep a lot and are discarded anyway after 1s). Using Swing Timers would avoid the thread-creation overhead, but be considerably more verbose.